# Can not clone cStringIO object properly

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have the following code to get an image from a url:

```
im = cStringIO.StringIO(image_buffer)
```

now i have to do different operations on the original image such as:

```
Image.open(im).crop(box=(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

but this will edit the im itsself so i can't reuse the Image.open command.

Therefore i would like to clone the im object. i have tried that by using the following:

```
copy.deepcopy(im)
copy.copy(im)
im[:]
```

But none of those seem to work, the copy ones even throw the following exception:

```
object.__new__(cStringIO.StringI) is not safe, use cStringIO.StringI.__new__()
```

I have tried to search for this error but it's not clear to me why it refuses to clone the im object.

This is written in python (using the django framework)

I am using the PIL library for image manipulations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a copy of a `cStringIO.StringIO` file object by simply getting out the string value and creating a new object, using the [`StringIO.getvalue()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue):

```
new_file = cStringIO.StringIO(original.getvalue())
```

That said, store a reference to the *image object* instead, and apply operations to that:

```
image = Image.open(im)
image.crop(box=(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

This then allows you to also save the image to a new file (in-memory or otherwise) after you applied all the transformations.

You can more easily create additional copies of an image object with the [`Image.copy()` method](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy):

```
image = Image.open(im)
image_copy = image.copy()
image.crop(box=(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Here `image_copy` remains uncropped.

Comment: How could i clone the image then when i use the last image?

Comment: @MaximGeerinck: by using the `Image.copy()` method.